# I am trying to upgrade from boost 1.68.0 to boost 1.77.0. But I am facing issue related to endpoint type

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I need to upgrade from boost 1.68.0 to boost 1.77.0.
So I downloaded boost 1.77.0 and built it.

But when I compile my code with boost I get the following error,

```
In file included from
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:36,
from
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core/stream_traits.hpp:16, from
..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core/basic_stream.hpp:18, from
..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core.hpp:16, from
..//include/restapp/APIHandlerDef.hpp:21, from
../src/services/ServiceReadPeriodic_A.cpp:11:
..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp: In
instantiation of 'class
boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0> >':
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:93:35:
    required from 'class
    boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0>, boost::asio::executor>'
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:60:7:
    required from 'class
    boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0> >'
 ..//include/restapp/Session.hpp:79:75:   required from here
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:57:39:
    error: no type named 'endpoint' in 'class
    boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0>'
    typedef typename Protocol::endpoint endpoint_type; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file
    included from
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core/stream_traits.hpp:16, from
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core/basic_stream.hpp:18, from
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core.hpp:16, from
   
 ..//include/restapp/APIHandlerDef.hpp:21, from
    ../src/services/ServiceReadPeriodic_A.cpp:11:
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp: In instantiation of
    'class
    boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0>, boost::asio::executor>':
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:60:7:
    required from 'class
    boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0> >'
 ..//include/restapp/Session.hpp:79:75:   required from here
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:100:39: error: no type
    named 'endpoint' in 'class
    boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0>'
    typedef typename Protocol::endpoint endpoint_type; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file
    included from
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core/basic_stream.hpp:20, from
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/beast/core.hpp:16, from
   
 ..//include/restapp/APIHandlerDef.hpp:21, from
    ../src/services/ServiceReadPeriodic_A.cpp:11:
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp: In
    instantiation of 'class
    boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>,
    0> >':
 ..//include/restapp/Session.hpp:79:75:   required from here
   
 ..//../bin/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:87:39: error:
    no type named 'endpoint' in 'class
    boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0>'
    typedef typename Protocol::endpoint endpoint_type; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The error is observed in multiple places but is same everywhere - no type named 'endpoint' in 'class boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0>'

I am stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You should try to narrow down the problem. Maybe you find the source of the error. If not you may be able to post a minimal reproducible example so it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're passing an executor somewhere where an endpoint is expected.

Using my crystal ball it seems likely that this happens somewhere where a `socket` is being constructed/assigned (restapp/Session.hpp:79).

Without seeing the code in `Session.hpp` or `ServiceReadPeriodic_A.cpp` there is no real way to say exactly why it's happening, but I expect it is because you have been (correctly) trying to replace references of type `io_service&` with copies of `io_context::get_executor()` or executors built from that.

However, the endpoint argument for socket constructors is optional and comes second, so something went wrong in the changes.

You'll have to show more or figure it out from here.